# Python 2.7.8: Socket - Client Server Data loss in TCP socket

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I just started with socket in python. I set up a basic client-server arrangement in  localhost using the following:

## for server:

```
from socket import *
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('', 6969))
s.listen(10)
c, a = s.accept()
while c.recv(100000) != '':
    print c.recv(100000)
```

## for client:

```
from socket import *
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('localhost', 6969))
while True:
    say = raw_input('Input Text: ')
    s.send(say)
```

Now, some data (50 %) is lost when I send it, which means it's not received by the server.

Screenshot :

[image]

Why is is so?

Can I do anything to improve the efficiency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the server you are calling `recv()` *twice*: first in the while loop condition, and then in the body of the loop. Each `recv()` consumes up to 100000 bytes from the socket, so you are effectively discarding the data from every second read.

Try this instead:

```
from socket import *
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('', 6969))
s.listen(10)
c, a = s.accept()

while True:
    data = c.recv(100000)
    if data:
        print data
    else:
        print "Client closed connection"
        break
```